# Setting reference to itself by default

Tags: postgresql

Let's assume my table looks like this:

```
user( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
name TEXT, root_id INTEGER NOT NULL
(foreign key to user.id) )
```

And what I want to achieve is to automatically assign the same value to root_id as is for the primary key.

It's not possible to use this expression

```
DEFAULT id
```

"cannot use column references in default expression"

So I have tried this approach next:

```
DEFAULT CURRVAL('user_id_seq')
```

but then I get: "currval of sequence "user_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session"

Of course I could define a trigger function and run it before insert... but maybe there's some more neat solution that you can suggest?

Comment: You could late change it via ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER column root_id SET DEFAULT currval(...)' ,  but that could cause race conditions. The convention is to let the root entries have NULL as a parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked in my test on 9.1, not sure why your attempt with `DEFAULT currval('user_id_seq')` failed..?

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
  "id" SERIAL,
  "name" TEXT,
  "root_id" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT currval('user_id_seq'),
  CONSTRAINT "user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
```

Then I checked it

```
INSERT INTO "user" ("name") VALUES('mike') RETURNING *;

 id | name | root_id
----+------+---------
  1 | mike |       1
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger to simulate this behavior:

```
CREATE FUNCTION user_default_trigger_function()
RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
  IF NEW.root_id IS NULL THEN
    NEW.root_id := NEW.id;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER users_default_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE user_default_trigger_function();
```